# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/user?search=tester from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, mern

"Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/user?search=tester from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED)," indicates that the frontend (running on localhost:3000) is trying to make a request to the backend API (http://127.0.0.1:5000/), but the connection is being refused.

In frotend is running on localhost:3000 and backend server is running on localhost:5000 unable to make request between frontend and backend.

I am expecting to fix or resolve the bug.

Comment: Are you using docker? What happens when you do a http request to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`? Please add some more details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.